# Search drop list styling

Tags: css

[input name="search" styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuzhq.png)

Hi everyone, Can you suggest how to style search drop list?

Comment: Custom plugin for dropdown (like select2 or other) and then use CSS

Comment: First you should try it yourself and when you have some code you can come back here and ask a specific question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` isn't what u would use for a droplist. I would recommend u use `<select>`for that.

if you want to have a simple search bar u can style it using this:

```
#search-bar {
position: absolute;

left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

border: none;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #333;

padding: 16px;
outline: none;
color: #fff;}
```

first portion of the code is to center the search bar in the center of the screen, the screen. Second portion is used to make it (in my opinion) look more clean.

Hope this solved your issue?